# How to twitter bootstrap dropdown menu hover and disable on click

Tags: css

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top marginBottom-0" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">NewWindow</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Active Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="page-header">Bootstrap 3.0.3<br>
        <small>Navbar - Click Dropdown - Sub - Sub - Sub - Sub ...</small></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
           <h1>You Like It ?</h1>
           <br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS code

```
.marginBottom-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #555;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for the mistake. my question is how to twitter bootstrap dropdown menu hover and disable on click

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing the opening `<nav>` tag which should look something like this:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

Regarding the hover, you can do this by using purely CSS `hover`:

```
.nav li.dropdown:hover>ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Please see the working snippet below:

```css
.marginBottom-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #555;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

.nav li.dropdown:hover>ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Active Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="page-header">Bootstrap 3.0.3<br>
    <small>Navbar - Click Dropdown - Sub - Sub - Sub - Sub ...</small></h1>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <h1>You Like It ?</h1>
    <br>
  </div>

</div>
```